# Factory 32U4 burning bootloader problem

Tags: arduino, usb, bootloader

[image: 32U4 circuit]I have a design utilizing the 32U4 and when I burn the bootloader on a factory fresh chip, it reports success but a problem occurs when I try to connect via a USB cable. My Win10 machine reports Unknown USB Device (Device descriptor Request Failed) each time I plug in the board.

The d+ and d- traces are 0.5mm width, 30mm long, of equal length between chip and socket with 22 ohm resistors in series with each.

Out of frustration, I have removed the IC from a pro micro and installed it on my board, and it just works as expected including USB.

So, is there any special sauce into getting a factory chip operational?

Edit: using the Arduno environment to burn the bootloader via a Uno programmed as ISP.

Comment: Did you program the fuse bits correctly, or just burned the bootloader?

Comment: Please post schematics of your board.

Comment: I just burned the bootloader, I am not aware the Arduino environment allows fuse manipulation?

Comment: The board and connections are working fine with an already programmed chip from the pro mini. The ICSP header is correct and the USB is correct, and the Arduino environment reports successful programming. I can also upload sketches via "upload using programmer" but no USB.

Comment: Have you connected VBUS (TQFP: pin 7) or UVCC (pin 2)?

Comment: Both VBus and UVcc are connected.

Comment: As an extra sanity check, how does your non-working micro behave if you put it on the pro mini board?

Comment: Going to give that a try.

Comment: Without more details,just a guess: but do you know that the chips come with `CLKDIV8` fuse bit enabled?  I confess I frequently forget it, and it puts all the timing off.   I don't know if Arduino software itself will program fuses, but AVRDUDE certainly does (and is I think included in Arduino suite).  See obviously the datasheet for definitivie, but http://eleccelerator.com/fusecalc/fusecalc.php?chip=atmega32u4 is very useful, with AVRDUDE commands.

Comment: the non working micro accepts sketches i.e. blink via icsp. After burning the bootloader via Arduino (uno) as ISP, non-functioning USB persists.

Comment: Tried these commands and they were accepted just fine but the problem persists. 1. "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17\bin\avrdude" "-CC:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17\etc\avrdude.conf" -v -patmega32u4 -carduino -PCOM16 -b19200 -e -Ulock:w:0x3F:m -Uefuse:w:0xcb:m -Uhfuse:w:0xd8:m -Ulfuse:w:0xff:m

Comment: 2. "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/bin/avrdude" "-CC:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17\etc\avrdude.conf" -v -patmega32u4 -carduino -PCOM16 -b19200 -e -Uflash:w:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6\bootloaders\caterina\Caterina-Leonardo.hex:i -Ulock:w:0x2F:m

Comment: When you progam blink into the CPU, does it work?  At the correct rate?  (It also looks to me like you have wrong L fuse as 0xff, [fuse calculator](http://eleccelerator.com/fusecalc/fusecalc.php?chip=atmega32u4) suggests `-U lfuse:w:0xC1:m `)